# .NET MDI child form suppress/hide caption/icon area

Tags: c#, windows-7, mdi, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have a subform (child) that I want to use in a number of parents.  I'm not a professional developer (I'm an architect - I know, you can save all the jokes... :) - working solo at present).  I've ended up using an MDI form with the subform as a child.  I maximize the subform form and most things are fine except that although I've tried to disable all the various widgets (the subform in the designer shows NO caption/icon/button area), I get TWO icons on the left and TWO sets of buttons on the right - of which ONLY the restore button works.  Either of the sets of buttons will work the one child form.

Is there any way around this?  I want the subform to be "transparent" the the user - they shouldn't be aware there's a subform in use.

I've done a quick search and I'd already suppressed the actual caption as mentioned in another answer - to get the caption bar suppressed in the designer...

Is MDI the right technology, or is there a better way to have the same subform appear in multiple parent forms?

VS2008, C#, Windows 7

TIA,
Paolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a WF bug that will double the glyphs if you create the MDI child form in the parent's constructor.  Here's an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        var child = new Form();
        child.MdiParent = this;
        child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        child.Show();
    }
}
```

Move the child form creation code to the Load event to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks Hans!

That's got rid of the "doubling up".  Now, is there any way to suppress the "bar" entirely?

Comment: No, everything is private, you cannot mess with it.  There is no point in using MDI if you always run the child forms maximized.

Comment: I do intend to use the child form maximized. So how do I couple the child with the parent without MDI - just a pointer would be good.  I'm just not sure what the mechanism to use is.  Remember , I'm just an architect (and a Data one at that! :) )

Comment: Thanks for the direction Hans, the UserControl is working and I now have some UserControl issues but the question I have has now been answered!